# shared library Missing symbol

Tags: c, linux, shared

I have C code for which I want to compile a shared library. This shared library is dependent on other FlexNet Publisher Libraries. I do not get any errors while compiling the library but during runtime I get

Missing symbol 'Ox410ef03750728897' required by '/home/user/workspaceforC/libMylibrary.so'

```
Missing symbol 'Ox410ef0495302ac72' required by '/home/user/workspaceforC/libMylibrary.so'
```

When I run nm libMylibrary.so I can see both the symbols:

U Ox410ef03750728897

U Ox410ef0495302ac72

It does not show me which library they are missing from.

I am clueless as to what is missing while compiling/linking.

I have the same code which I made JNI compatible and compiled to the shared library using the same makefile. I can successfully load it and run it in eclipse for Java.

Please advice. What could U with just a memory address mean and how can I resolve it?
I did a readelf and it shows:

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]

0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]

LD_LIBRARY_PATH is set to /lib64 where all these 3 libraries are located.

Please advice.

Comment: The "U" at the beginning of those lines of `nm`'s output says that the symbols are *undefined* in that library, though they are referenced by it, else they would not be listed at all.

Comment: Note also that although those symbol names are unusual, they are *not* numeric, not even in a C-style hexadecimal constant sense.  The first character of each is a capital Latin letter "O", not a zero (0).

Comment: Evidently, the library that actually defines the symbols in question is not listed as a NEEDED library of libMylibrary.so.  I can't speak to how that might have happened, because you've not presented any build information.  You *do* say that the lib is dependent on "other FlexNet Publisher Libraries", however, so a good guess would be that one or more of those defines the symbols.  One solution would be to specify the appropriate one in the link options for the executable.

Comment: It is infact 0x (zero). The text didn't quite copy right here. I compiled the same code  to be used from Java. I added JNI declarations to do so. That library compiled fine. I could also load that library from eclipse and run it successfully. Exact same linking options to the FlexNet libraries were used.
So wondering why is the pure 'C' library is throwing runtime errors.

Comment: Missing symbol 'Ox410ef0495302ac72' required by '/home/user/workspaceforC/libMylibrary.so' 

just does not give enough information about what I need to fix.

Comment: Are these really symbols or just memory addresses Ox410ef0495302ac72

Comment: I'm having trouble believing that your mysterious symbols start with the digit zero, because such a symbol is not a valid identifier in C.  Moreover, "The text didn't quite copy right" seems unlikely if you used copy&paste as you ought to have done, nor even if you unwisely transcribed by hand.  But none of that alters anything else I already said.  Your library does not provide definitions of the symbols, whatever they are, so link in the one that does.